Are the laws of physics brute facts or metaphysical necessities?
Definitions

Brute fact: In contemporary philosophy, a brute fact is a fact that cannot be explained in terms of a deeper, more "fundamental" fact. There are two main ways to explain something: say what "brought it about", or describe it at a more "fundamental" level. For example, a cat displayed on a computer screen can be explained, more "fundamentally", in terms of certain voltages in bits of metal in the screen, which in turn can be explained, more "fundamentally", in terms of certain subatomic particles moving in a certain manner. If one were to keep explaining the world in this way and reach a point at which no more "deeper" explanations can be given, then one would have found some facts which are brute or inexplicable, in the sense that we cannot give them an ontological explanation. As it might be put, there may exist some things that just are. To reject the existence of brute facts is to think that everything can be explained ("Everything can be explained" is sometimes called the principle of sufficient reason).
Metaphysical necessity: In philosophy, metaphysical necessity, sometimes called broad logical necessity, is one of many different kinds of necessity, which sits between logical necessity and nomological (or physical) necessity, in the sense that logical necessity entails metaphysical necessity, but not vice versa, and metaphysical necessity entails physical necessity, but not vice versa. A proposition is said to be necessary if it could not have failed to be the case. Nomological necessity is necessity according to the laws of physics and logical necessity is necessity according to the laws of logic, while metaphysical necessities are necessary in the sense that the world could not possibly have been otherwise. What facts are metaphysically necessary, and on what basis we might view certain facts as metaphysically but not logically necessary are subjects of substantial discussion in contemporary philosophy.

In the context of the philosophy of physics and metaphysics, what status do the laws of physics hold? Are they considered brute facts (lacking further explanation) or metaphysically necessary facts (somehow self-explanatory)? Or are there philosophers who propose alternative views beyond these two options? If there are multiple views on this, what would be an overview of them and the arguments presented for each one?

Addendum - Other Types of Necessity (source)

Metaphysical necessity is contrasted with other types of necessity. For example, the philosophers of religion John Hick and William L. Rowe distinguished the following three:

factual necessity (existential necessity): a factually necessary being is not causally dependent on any other being, while any other being is causally dependent on it.
causal necessity (subsumed by Hick under the former type): a causally necessary being is such that it is logically impossible for it to be causally dependent on any other being, and it is logically impossible for any other being to be causally independent of it.
logical necessity: a logically necessary being is a being whose non-existence is a logical impossibility, and which therefore exists either timeless or eternally in all possible worlds.



Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

The universe is the way it is. There is no scientific theory explaining why it is the way it is.

Science observes phenomena and attempts to explain these phenomena
by reducing them to general laws of nature. But science does
not explain why just these laws, e.g., why the fundamental constants
like the speed of light, the charge of the electron, the Planck
constant etc. have just the actual values.
You may call that
accepting the laws of physics as a brute fact.

Not everyone is content with this state of affairs. Hence different
people have invented a series of speculations about possible
reasons behind these brute facts: The anthropic principle, the
multiverse concept, different kinds of religious speculation about   a
creator, etc.
Some of these speculations are
interesting and broaden the scope of our thinking. But neither of them derives from a more basic scientific cosmology.

Metaphysical necessity seems to be a controversial concept.    Sometimes it is described as

If something could not have been
otherwise, no matter how the world had turned out, that thing is
metaphysically necessary.

A paraphrase like this does not help when asking about the world as a whole.
Hence  at this point the
OP’s question goes beyond what philosophy of nature is able to
achieve.



"different people have invented a series of speculations about possible reasons behind these brute facts". While this is true in general, there is one correct reason (which we cannot determine). This correct reason was not invented by humans. So if it is God - and He has given His revelation to some people - then I wouldn't call it an invention.

@returntrue History shows that religious revelations are controversial, both with respect to their existence and with respect to their truth.

Yes. Therefore I would distinguish between religions - man-made theories and made-up revelations - and the truth - something we do not surely know, but which could be God and God-given.

This question makes two invalid framing assumptions, which lead to a misleading statement of the question being asked.
Mistake 1, science laws are not unbreakable "laws" they are regularities, and are broken.  See this paper explaining how all laws in physics are broken:  https://www.pnas.org/doi/10.1073/pnas.93.25.14256
Mistake 2, global reductionism has failed, and it is not true that everything reduces to physics.  See SEP section 5:  https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/scientific-reduction/
Rephrasing to avoid these errors, your question is: "are any aspects of our universe metaphysically necessary, either within or outside science?"
Since scientific laws are breakable, they are by definition not "necessary", so your original phrasing is answered in the negative.
Rather than laws or any other science properties being "necessary" science itself is committed to science being contingent, and the discoveries of science to be "brute facts" that could have been otherwise.
So -- science cannot be the subject area where methodological necessity might lie. The alternative that analytic philosophers sometimes invoke, as to what other than science might provide necessity in this world, is mathematics or logic.  Here is an example paper that explores this possibility:  https://philarchive.org/archive/NOLTEO#:~:text=A%20lot%20of%20philosophers%20engage,status%20of%20%E2%80%9Cmetaphysical%20necessity%E2%80%9D.
However, both mathematics and logic are infinite in possible forms: https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/think/article/abs/guide-to-logical-pluralism-for-nonlogicians/EDFDFA1C9EB65DB71848DABD6B12D877  And what math or logic applies to a particular aspect of our world, is once again a contingent question.  One might be able to derive metaphysically necessary conclusion within a specified logic and/or math system.  But try to apply that conclusion to THIS world, and it becomes a contingent/brute question whether that is the right math or logic.

2 sounds like a bold, and unproven, claim especially since reduction has many different meanings. There is 0 evidence that everything does not reduce to, or atleast supervene on, physics.

@Syed You can assert personal "wish it were so" beliefs all you want, but argument by incredulity is still a fallacy, as is denial of the existence of cited evidence.

@Dcleve I don't think that the paper you link claims that natural laws are broken. It certainly doesn't claim all laws are broken. It merely clarifies the role of symmetry breaking in fundamental physics. Symmetry also plays a role in phase transitions in everyday physics like the melting of ice into water. Ice has different properties than liquid water, and hence different behaviour. Nobody will claim that you have broken any physical laws here by melting ice.

@Dcleve Out of curiosity, could you give an example of something that does not reduce to physics? I know chemistry is supposed  to supervene on physics, but we can not solve the exact wave functions for chemical bonding and have to resort to approximations with perturbation theory. But this is like the three-body problem: just because we can't find a general analytical solution, and therfore can only find approximations, doesn't mean that this invalidates Newton's laws...

@Philomath Reduction is a very powerful and useful heuristic, and the critiques of global reduction do not propose that nothing reduces, just that not everything does.  My go-to examples are species, ecosystem, and ecological niches.  The theory behind emergence was elaborated in the Phil of Mind theory of functionalism, where the FUNCTION is what consciousness was identical to, independent of the substrata.  Functions are emergent in functionalism.  Complex systems theory has also abandoned global reduction.  See these three recent paper examples:

https://www.nas.ewi.tudelft.nl/people/Piet/papers/robustness_complex_nets.pdf https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/behavioral-and-brain-sciences/article/abs/brain-disorders-not-really-why-network-structures-block-reductionism-in-psychopathology-research/D5A20455723B237C60E379D29F8797B1 https://www.mdpi.com/2079-8954/12/1/2  The first does not explicitly reject reduction, but it describes common behavior across wildly different systems, most of which are difficult to even identify possible reduction approaches.  The next two explicitly challenge global reductionism.

@Dcleve Thank you! Just for my understanding, does your claim that global reductionism has failed imply strong emergence?

@Philomath -- What to replace global reduction with as a heuristic is still a work in progress.  Most of science has recognized that emergence is a real phenomenon, and that "weak emergence" does not adequately describe it.  There is a lot of hesitation to accept "strong emergence" though, because that breaks physicalism's causal closure principle.  There is a lot of waffling about "medium emergence", rather than biting the bullet and admitting that causal closure already failed multiple test cases already (science is open, physics is indeterminate), adding in strong emergence is no issue.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Both.
Going by your post, a brute fact would be one that has no further explanation.
Something that is metaphysically necessary can have a further explanation. For example, in a deterministic universe, and assuming that the laws are necessary, everything by extension becomes necessary. However, this does not mean that there is no explanation for where I come from, even though I now become metaphysically necessary. In this case, the further explanation would be the biological processes that created me.
However, if the laws of nature have no further cause, then they de facto become a brute fact (for this reason) and metaphysically necessary (since by definition, they are physically necessary if those are the only laws that operate).
